# eclipse remote project with sftp - dltk indexing results in 'no more sessions' error

Tags: eclipse, ssh, sftp, dltk

I am running a virtualbox with debian installed as local webserver. I am working with eclipse directly on that virtual box with a remote project (RSE plugin). I am having the problem that eclipse starts the DLTK-indexer as soon as I open the project. On the debian machine, instantly my /var/log/auth.log is filling up with a endless list of:

```
sshd[4271]: error: no more sessions
```

In eclipse, the error log is filling up with (although using JRE 6):

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Operation failed. File system input or output error: rse://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/path/to/file/being/indexed
org.eclipse.rse.services.files.RemoteFileIOException: Operation failed. File system input or output error
```

While indexing is done, I am not able to save any file I am working on, as all ssh-sessions are already used on the server.
It seems that the indexing process tries to open a new connection for every file it´s indexing.

When indexing is finished, everything works normal again, I can save files etc.
I would appreciate the indexer to complete its work, but as code completion does not work afterwards, eclipse was not able to do the indexing.

One solution would be to disable the indexing, but this is not the purpose of an IDE, code completion is one of the few reasons for me to still use an IDE (at least for large projects).

Any ideas on how to make indexing work and get rid of the ssh-errors would be great!

#### Futher system information:

**Host-System:** Windows 7 Prof. 64bit
**Guest-System (virtualbox)**: Debian Lenny with sftp subsystem enabled
**Eclipse:** Indigo with Zend PDT and RSE (already running with Java 6 JRE 1.6.0_45)

Thanks for your help!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by doing two things:

1. set up ssh to use multiplexing (see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Multiplexing) in the virtual machine
2. Upgrade eclipse to Kepler 64Bit release (much faster and more stable in Windows 7) with manual installation of PDT feature (using Zend PDT is a waste of time)

This also works with Java7!

Now I have completely indexed projects and can use code-completion!